# Netbeans Jade templates plugin

Tags: netbeans, plugins, pug

Is there a Jade template plugin other than https://github.com/lumenlunae/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is - now! An improved version of the lumenlunae version on Github.  It works with NetBeans 8 too.

https://github.com/blackcape/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting-nb8

Comment: Does anyone find that this plug-in does not work in NB 8.0.2, even with the Jade File Type and Jade Syntax Highlighter installed?

Comment: What is needed to install this into Netbeans 8.0.2 on Linux? I have tried the nbm's from https://github.com/blackcape/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting-nb8 https://github.com/monkeini/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting-nb8 https://github.com/lumenlunae/jade-netbeans-syntax-highlighting but I haven't got any to be recognized. I have tried Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugins... (and select the two nbm's together and separately) also tried adding them to ~/.netbeans/8.0.1/modules/

Comment: @jeffbuhrt sorry don't know, I'm on windows for my sins.  Although I am also using Mac from time to time, different projects, think I have it there too and it works.

Comment: Note, that `jade` was recently renamed to `pug`

Answer (score 0):

The last version of `NetBeans` (8.2) includes `Jade` syntax highlight and validation.